# Show that the session expired and force the user to relogin (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, php, session, firefox

We use an internal system (with FF as default browser)

I'd like that if the PHP session on the server side has expired (or after some time of inactivity on the client side) the message should been shown to the client . So the user is forced to log in again. 
What is the best way to realize it?
We can use a polling and check with ajax ah server script if session exists. 
But maybe there is a beter way?

Comment: If the session has expired the user will (should depending on your code) be required to login again anyway

Comment: you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php to be sure that the session is finished

Comment: You could always pass the timeout of the session to the JS, use a `setTimeout()` for that duration, check to make sure that the session is still invalid then show an alert that says something like "Your session has expired" and then redirect to the login page when it closes, if they didn't expire then just set another timeout to the same function for the remaining time